# Simple jQuery call to change input value continues returning TypeError $(...) is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

My hair is falling out while I'm trying to figure out why jQuery keeps throwing a TypeError for what I think is a valid call to replace an input value in the HTML.

The line below is being called in one of my functions to change all of the input values for those with the name "form_key."

$('input[name="form_key"]').val("ItWorks!");

(resides in http://vt2.net/js/warp/warp.js)

There are multiple pages that have this hidden input name and some pages have it more than once, and I'm trying to change the value for all on the page.

The page below only has one  but Firebug keeps showing a TypeError no matter how many ways I try to replace the value.
http://vt2.net/my-test-product.html

It's probably something really simple and stupid but I keep missing it! Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `$` === `jQuery`?

Comment: you could paste the full error message and it might get a lot more clear.

Comment: an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice too.

Comment: @KevinB you are right.. `$` is not `jQuery` on http://vt2.net/my-test-product.html.

Comment: My bad. It must be straight javascript. The original code as it was written had that line as: $$('[name="form_key"]')[0].value = formkey; but it would have the same error.  I was trying to troubleshoot it by dumbing it down but if it's not jquery, then my statement obviously won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You already use

```
http://vt2.net/js/lib/jquery/noconflict.js
```

where define

```
// Avoid PrototypeJS conflicts, assign jQuery to $j instead of $
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

So for all operation by jQuery, you need use `$j` instead just `$`

And your `$` now from *prototype.js*

```
function $(element) {
  if (arguments.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0, elements = [], length = arguments.length; i < length; i++)
      elements.push($(arguments[i]));
    return elements;
  }
  if (Object.isString(element))
    element = document.getElementById(element);
  return Element.extend(element);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Kevin B is right `$` is not `jQuery` on http://vt2.net/my-test-product.html.

Use

```
jQuery('input[name="form_key"]').val("ItWorks!");
```

Or

```
jQuery.noConflict()
```

Comment: would anybody care to explain why downvote for the answer